# How to prevent word splitting without preventing empty string removal?

Tags: bash, parameter, null

I need to pass as a program argument a parameter expansion. The expansion results in a filename with spaces.  Therefore, I double-quote it to have the filename as a single word: `"$var"`.

As long as `$var` contains a filename, the program gets a single-word argument and it works fine.  However, at times the expansion results in an empty string, which when passed as argument, breaks the program (which I cannot change).

Not removing the empty string is the specified behavior, according to Bash Reference Manual:

> If a parameter with no value is expanded within double quotes, a null argument results and is retained.

But then, how do I manage the case where I need to quote variables, but also need to discard an empty string expansion?

EDIT:

Thanks to George Vasiliou, I see that a detail is missing in my question (just tried to keep it short :) ).  Running the program is a long java call, which abbreviated looks like this:

```
java -cp /etc/etc MyClass param1 param2 "$var" param4
```

Indeed, using an `if` statement like that described by George would solve the problem.  But it would require one call with "$var" in the `then` clause and another without "$var" in the `else` clause.

To avoid the repetition, I wanted to see if there is a way to use a single call that discards the expansion of "$var" when it is empty.

Comment: it's easy: always quote variables

Comment: Sorry, but it is still not clear. What should be passed to the command if `$var` is empty? Is `$var` an argument to `param2` so we also need to remove `param2`? Or do you just want to run `java . . . param1 param2 param4`? Unless `$var` is an argument to an option, I don't see how having it there could make any difference if it is empty.

Comment: If $var is empty, I need to call "java ... param1 param2 param4".  $var is not an argument to param2.

Comment: This question has an answer [here](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/80216/#286350).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `${parameter:+word}` [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) form seems to do the job

```
( xyz=2; set -- ${xyz:+"$xyz"}; echo $# )
1

( xyz=; set -- ${xyz:+"$xyz"}; echo $# )
0

( unset xyz; set -- ${xyz:+"$xyz"}; echo $# )
0
```

So that should translate to

```
program ${var:+"$var"}
```

in your case

Comment: IMHO, this is exactly what the OP is expecting. I have edited the answer to change `${var+...}` to `${var:+...}` because it is clear from the OP that no substitution must occur if variable is set but empty

Comment: And indeed, this is exactly what I needed.  Works seamlessly.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

In `bash` and shells with similar array support you can do the following:

```sh
# default is an empty array
param=()

# if $var is not empty then add it to array
[[ "$var" ]] && param=("$var")

# use the $@-like magic for arrays
java -cp /etc/etc MyClass param1 param2 "${param[@]}" param4
```

#### Demo

```sh
demo() {
  [[ "$var" ]] && param=("$var") || param=()

  echo -n 'output: '
  printf '<%s> ' before "${param[@]}" after
  echo
}

demo # output: <before> <after> 

var=''
demo # output: <before> <after> 

var='foo bar'
demo # output: <before> <foo bar> <after>
```

#### Note

See also https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2086#exceptions where the approach from *iruvar*'s answer is also explained again.

Comment: This is a great addition to iruvar's answer.  For calls with many similar arguments, they can be placed in the array, and expanded from it, in the way you explain.

Comment: @phk good to know... nice answer.

Comment: after many attempts and google searches, I´ve had to use this `${VAR[@]}` thing that I don't understand - thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Is not clear what you are trying to do, but isn't a simple if enough? 
For example:

```
[[ ! -z "$var" ]] && call_program_with_arg "$var"
```

Or

```
if [[ ! -z "$var" ]];then call_program "$var";fi
```

If $var is empty then nothing hapens. If is not empty then call the program you want.

After Question Update:

```
parameters=( "Param1" "Param2" )
[[ ! -z "$var" ]] && parameters+=( "$var" "Param4") || parameters+=( "Param4" )
java -cp /etc/etc MyClass "${parameters[@]}"
```

Testing:

```
$parameters=( "Param1" "Param2" );var="my file.java";[[ ! -z "$var" ]] && parameters+=( "$var" "Param4") || parameters+=( "Param4" );echo java -cp /etc/etc MyClass "${parameters[@]}"                                                                                                              
>java -cp /etc/etc MyClass Param1 Param2 my file.java Param4
$parameters=( "Param1" "Param2" );var="";[[ ! -z "$var" ]] && parameters+=( "$var" "Param4") || parameters+=( "Param4" );echo java -cp /etc/etc MyClass "${parameters[@]}"                                                                                                               
>java -cp /etc/etc MyClass Param1 Param2 Param4
```